# inserting in mongo forEach continues for ever

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating some fake documents by 'expanding' the existing documents by 20 times.  But; the forEach loop never seems to end.  Why?

```
db['COLLECTION'].find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    for( var x = 0; x < 20; x++ ) {
            delete doc['_id'];
            doc['Author'] = randArrayElement(names); /* chooses random name */
            doc['Description'] = buzzword(); /* makes something up*/

            db['COLLECTION'].insert(doc);
        }
    }
 )
```

Comment: Is it adding any records to the collection and just taking forever or not inserting anything?

Comment: The documents are being added to the collection.  It just seems to never stop adding them.  I had 50 documents and would expect 50 x 20, but there seem to be 20 thousand plus inserted.

Comment: Did you ever find out why? I have to do something similar, and wondered if you can pass on any tips? Was it because you had the for loops inside the forEach? Just spitballing, but i basically just need to transfer docs from one server to the next, but don't want 10K+, if i only have 1000. Any guidance would be appreciated with this question/answer.

Comment: The use of snapshot fixed it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use [snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/snapshot/) here:

```
db['COLLECTION'].find().snapshot().forEach(function(doc){
  ...
})
```

I assume that this happens because write operations might result in a move of the document and snapshot fixes it:

> The $snapshot operator prevents the cursor from returning a document
>   more than once because an intervening write operation results in a
>   move of the document.

If this will not help, then I have another idea that the newly created documents are picked up by the cursor. To overcome this I would create an array of all the documents, and then separately iterate them and do your 20 inserts for each one.